# Replacing confirm exit dialogue by custom dialogue in Eclipse RCP 3.x application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to replace the application exit dialogue by custom dialogue or in other word I want to get a hook on click of exit button on workbench window, so I can show messages in dialogue. Currently I am adding window listener and on window close event I perform some operations, but this event is triggered only after the window gets closed.

Is there any way of adding a hook for this. I am using eclipse 3.x application.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your `org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor` you can override `preShutdown()`

```java
@Override
public boolean preShutdown() {
    return MessageDialog.openConfirm(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Shutdown?", "Should I shutdown?");
}
```

Your `WorkbenchAdvisor` should lay in the plugin where your application is delared APPLICATIONNAMEWorkbenchAdvisor.

Comment: Hi... I am using existing application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.application". I don't have IApplication class, as I digged it uses "org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor" , how can i access this class . Hope I am explaining propery

Comment: Ok thought you have your own RCP application. I don't know if there is an hook for this. The dialog is opened here:  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.promptOnExit(Shell). You probalby will need to set IDEInternalPreferences.EXIT_PROMPT_ON_CLOSE_LAST_WINDOW to false, so the default dialog is not prompted.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to "org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.promptOnExit(S‌​hell)". I am adding aspectj over that method and doing custom operations than setting preference value (it says discouraged access). It works fine now . I don't know adding aspetj is right way. Thank once again :)